# Перехват прерывания клавиатуры

Tags: ассемблер, dos

Нужно написать простой обработчик 9ого прерывания. Чтобы во время вывода текста на консоль по нажатию Ctrl+C вывести другое сообщение, в данном случае !!!sucsess!!!. Вот что у меня есть. Вроде бы должно работать, но то ли я не успеваю во время вывода нажать, то ли что-то не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста или в чём проблема или вывести текст медленнее.

```
org  100h

jmp start

old_int09h dw ?
letter dw 'c'  

message db "!!!sucsess!!!$"     
text db "lazy dog jumps over red fox.$"

start:  
mov ax, @DATA   
mov ds, ax

; сохранить адрес предыдущего обработчика прерывания 09h
mov ax, 3509h
int 21h
mov word ptr old_int09h, bx
mov word ptr old_int09h+2, es

; установить наш обработчик
mov ax,2509h
mov dx,offset int09h_handler
int 21h 

mov ah, 9h
mov dx, offset text
int 21h


; восстановить предыдущий обработчик прерывания
mov ax,2509h
mov dx,word ptr old_int09h+2
mov ds,dx
mov dx,word ptr cs:old_int09h
int 21h

ret

int09h_handler proc far
pusha     
push es    ; сохранить ВСЕ регистры    
push ds
push cs
pop ds

push 0040h
pop ds
mov di, word ptr ds:001Ah  ; адрес головы буфера клавиатуры 
cmp di, word ptr ds:001Ch  ; если он равен адресу хвоста,
je exit_handler            ; буфер пуст, и нам делать нечего

mov ax, word ptr [di]     ; иначе: считать символ  
cmp ah, byte ptr letter 
jne exit_handler

mov al, byte ptr ds:0017h  ; считать байт состояния клавиатуры,
test al, 04h             ; если не нажат Ctrl,         
jz exit_handler          ; выйти,   

mov ah, 9h               ;если все условия выполнены вывожу сообщение
mov dx, offset message
int 21h

mov word ptr ds:001Ch, di ;установить адреса  головы и хвоста буфера                               
                           ;одинаковыми, пометив его тем самым как пустой       
exit_handler:
pop ds             ; восстановить все регистры
pop es
popa
jmp cs:old_int09h

int09h_handler endp   ; передать управление предыдущему обработчику
```

Comment: Где вы только такой пример нашли. Во первых как вы хотите успеть что то нажать, если после установки обработчика вы выводите сообщение и тут же завершаетесь. Сообщение за миллисекунду выведется... Во вторых странно читать символ из буфера клавиатуры, до того как вызван оригинальный обработчик, который туда что то положит. Ну и менять обработчики dos вызовами ... imho перебор, работаете на таком уровне, меняйте его сами в таблице прерываний. И использовать int 21h внутри обработчика аппаратного прерывания по хорошему нельзя, потому что int 21h не реентерабелен

Comment: @Mike Такое задание, не я его писал. Заменил вывод сообщения на его ввод, всё равно не работает, в docboxе сразу вылетает. _менять обработчики dos вызовами ... imho перебор_ Это имеет большое значение для небольшой лабораторной? _И использовать int 21h внутри обработчика аппаратного прерывания по хорошему нельзя_ Просто нужно как-то обозначить, что перехват сработал.

Comment: Конечно система вылетит, Вы же небось ожидание ввода делаете функцией dos. И из прерывания вызываете dos. Вот и получаете вложенный вызов не реентерабельной функции. Вы строку функциями  bios выводите, а не 21h. Ну или записью в видеопамять, оно так как то проще (imho). И когда вы делаете `cmp ah, byte ptr letter` у вас в DS 40h, вы до своей letter не доберетесь. Про существование ES не забывайте. Ну и чуть позже вы то самое 9-21h вызываете для вывода строки, а ds продолжает быть 40h